Given $AB=0$ prove that if $Ax=0$ has finitely many solutions then $Bx=0$ has infinitely many

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ , s.t $AB=0$, then if $Ax=0$ has finitely many solutions then $Bx=0$ has infinitely many solutions.

Here is where I am stuck :
I started by saying that if $Ax=0$ has  finitely many solutions then it has only one solution which is the trivial ${0}$,  the proof that I have written :
if $\overrightarrow{c}$ is a solution to $Ax=0$ Then $\alpha \cdot\overrightarrow{c} | \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is also a solution, therefore, there are infinitely many solutions, therefore it can only have either one solution or infinitely many, from the given info it has finitely many solutions, therefore, it has one trivial solution.
If $Ax=0$ has one solution then $\text{rank}(A)=n$  ....
I also tried that
$$Ax=0=AB=Bx$$
and got nowhere.

well, det(B)=0 ...

@An_Elephant without using Determinant, still haven't learned it yet

You are on the right way. You know that $AB=0$ means that any vector $y$ when multiplied by $AB$ yields $0$, so you have infinite number of solutions. Then $$ABy=A(By)=0$$
You can now write $By=x$, and since $Ax=0$ has only one solution $x=0$ you get $By=0$. But we mentioned that $y$ has infinite solutions ...

very understandable, thanks.

Have I understood correctly that $A,B∈R^{n×n}$? $A$ is injective for the reasons mentioned and thus, by the rank-nullity theorem, also bijective and therefore invertible. Then, by applying $A^{-1}$ to both sides, it follows that $B = 0$ or am I mistaken?"
